# Component receive list as parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular-components

I need my component to receive a list of objects to use. But I'm getting the following error:

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ("
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li [ERROR ->]*ngFor="let item of {{items}}">
        <a href="#paper">{{item.id}}</a>
      </li>
```

dropdow-cp.component.ts:

```
export class PfDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

@Input() items;

}
```

dropdow-cp.component.html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li *ngFor="let item of {{items}}">
        <a href="#paper">{{item.id}}</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

dashborad.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'dashboard-cmp',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html'
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{


  @Input() lista = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
    { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
  ]

}
```

dashborad.component.html

```
{{lista}}

    <pf-dropdown items="{{lista}}"></pf-dropdown>
```

When calling the {{lista}} tween is not displayed, it is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<li *ngFor="let item of items">` and
`<pf-dropdown [items]="lista"></pf-dropdown>`

You don't need interpolation (i.e. the curly braces '{{}}') as ngFor will take your string as expression which in return will check either for an array in your template or your component class (the .ts file).

Comment: and you should use <pf-dropdown [items]="lista"></pf-dropdown>